# What type of formula should i use

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two basic issues.

First is that, I'm trying to Count Yes & No entries in the Row.

Other one is, if NOs are either 3 or 4 Formula should return 1 and if NOs are 6 or higher it should return 2 in a Cell.

I have already tried  =(Roundup(Counta...)), but it doesn't works.

Any guess?

Comment: Since you have not mentioned that what would happen if NOs will 6 or what therefore I've included the condition to make the query more meaning full . If you want to set other value/condition just edit the question.

Comment: @Rajesh, case matters.  In your edit, you changes OP's lower case "yes" and "no" to upper case.

Comment: @Catalin, Rajesh tried to make it understandable, but  it's still not exactly clear what you want to accomplish.  Please explain more clearly.  Does the number go up after every 3 no's? e.g. 3, 4 or 5 no's = 1, 6,7 or 8 = 2?

Comment: @Bandersnatch, in general Case doesn't matters, unless we do not apply EXACT like,             =IF(SUMPRODUCT(EXACT("no",G62:G67)+0)>=3,1,"") or =IF(COUNT(INDEX(FIND("no",G62:G67),))>=3,1,"").

Comment: You're correct and I'm not, which is absolutely mortifying.

Comment: @ Bandersnatch yes. 3 no's = 1; 4 no's = 1; 4 no's = 1; 5 no's = 1; 6 no's = 2 and so on... 9 no's = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clear explanation of what you're trying to do.  You'll need a formula similar to this one:

`=TRUNC(COUNTIF(A1:M1,"No")/3,0)`

Change the range A1:M1 to the appropriate location of your data.

How it works:

The COUNTIF() counts the number of "No's" in the range, and that number is divided by 3.  So counts of 3,4 or 5 will give an intermediate result of 1.xxx, where xxx represents some decimals.  Similarly, counts of 6,7, or 8 will give 2.xxx, counts of 9,10 or 11 will give 3.xxx, and so forth.

The TRUNC() function truncates the result to 0 decimal places, essentially removing the .xxx's.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Note: if you find this answer helpful, please click on the grey checkmark at the top left to accept the answer and remove it from the unanswered queue.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's it. It worked exactly like I needed to. Thank you very much and to the other guys for their help :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a nested COUNTIF with an IF for this to work.

The forumla I used was =IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"no")>=3,1,"") though you can change this to however you need it based on range and what you want in the cell if there are less than 3 "no" in the cells.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you very much. Unfortunately this formula doesn't work exactly like I wanted. To be specific, after 3 no's I get the result "1" but, after another 3 no's (so 6 no's in total in range) the result remains "1". Maybe I wasn't so specific in my initial question. I would like the result to change to "2" after another 3 no's.